# name.exe has stopped working backtracking

Tags: c, backtracking

For n=2k (n even), display all parentheses which close corectly.

```
in:4

out: (()), ()()
```

Why does my program display "exe has stopped working" when I run it ? Did I do something wrong with the loops or is my approach on this problem wrong ?

```
 #include<stdio.h>


    int v[10],n;

    void readfile()
    {
        FILE*fin;

        fin=fopen("in.txt", "rt");

        if(fin==NULL)
            printf("Error");
        else{
            fscanf(fin, "%d", n);
        }
        fclose(fin);
    }

    void writefile()
    {

        int j;
        FILE*fout;


        fout=fopen("out.txt", "wt");

        if(fout==NULL)
            printf("Error");
        else{
            readfile();
            for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
                if(v[j]==1)
                    fprintf(fout, "%c", 41);
                else
                    fprintf(fout, "%c", 40);
        }
        fclose(fout);
    }

    int condition(int k)
    {
        int close=0, open=0, i;
        readfile();

        for(i=1; i<=k; i++)
            if(v[i]==0)
                open++;
            else
                close++;

        return open<=n/2 && close <= open;

    }

    void backtracking(int k)
    {
        int i;
        readfile();
        for(i=0; i<=1; i++)
        {
            v[k]=i;

            if(condition(k))

                if(k==n)
                    writefile();
                else
                    backtracking(k+1);
        }
    }

    void main()
    {
        backtracking(1);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger like gdb?

Comment: `fscanf(fin, "%d", n);` --> fscanf(fin, "%d", &n);

Comment: No, but i don't think the debugger is the problem.

Comment: On a funnier note: `No, but i don't think the debugger is the problem`--- it is never a problem, anyways. :-)

Comment: `fout=fopen("out.txt", "wt");` : first time `"w"`, then `"a"`.

Comment: No `void main()`, please. The prototype is `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code, here is one problem in this line:

```
fscanf(fin, "%d", n);
```

You should use this instead:

```
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n);
```

Because when you use the `fscanf()` function, you need to pass pointers instead of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your program.

Put a breakpoint in

```
fin=fopen("in.txt", "rt");
```

and check if the file was opened correctly.

if fin is NULL, your program will crash because fclose will have trouble with the null fin.

(The code you posted does not compile because `deschise` is not defined)

Comment: I forgot to translate in english that, line, it's not the problem, the program it's in my own language open in english,                                           fin=fopen("in.txt", "rt"), opens correctly, i even try the program without using any files, still it display exe stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

`fout=fopen("out.txt", "wt");`  Content is deleted every time.
So should be `fout=fopen("out.txt", "at");`

and delete a file in main.

```
int main(void)
{
    remove("out.txt");
    backtracking(1);
    return 0;
}
```